# Program which will take an array of block pieces and arrange them, if possible, to form a square in 4 x 4 grid

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a program, which will take an array of block pieces and arrange them, if possible, to form a square in 4 x 4 grid.

The pieces could be of any shape within 4 X 4 grid. If it is not possible I should return null.

Input :

```
Blocks[] pieces = new Blocks[4]
pieces[0] = new Blocks(1, new int[][]{{1, 1, 1}})
pieces[1] = new Blocks(2, new int[][]{{1, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}})
pieces[2] = new Blocks(3, new int[][]{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}})
pieces[3] = new Blocks(4, new int[][]{{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}})
```

Output :
The method will return square grid of 4x4 matrix as

```
2   1   1   1 
2   3   3   3 
2   3   4   3 
2   4   4   4
```

[Please see the explanation for the output here](http://www.imageuploading.net/images/12137/explanation-for-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This puzzle is pretty much the same as the famous *eight queens puzzle*, so look up that problem, see how it is solved, and try to apply this new knowledge to this puzzle.

The main diffeerence is that your blocks have a more complicated shape than a queen, but the rest is quite the same.

The basic ingredients to the solution are methods for the following tasks:

- does a certain block fit at a certain position on the grid?
- place a certain block at a certain position on the grid.
- take away a certain block from its position on the grid.

When you write methods for these three tasks, you only need some backtracking, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Just brute-force it. Try all possible positions of the blocks and see if they work. The general problem for an NxN grid is NP-complete so this is pretty much as good of a solution as you'll get.

Comment: I am trying to write a java program, how can i check by brute-forcing??

Comment: Brute-forcing means you can try all the possibilities until you find one that fits. May be you would like to read about backtracking.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking